# Why do I get undefined index while using simple array function

Tags: php, arrays, function, for-loop, cycle

This is my example array:

```
$arrayy[0]=48.72;
$arrayy[1]=21.32;
$arrayy[2]=48.62;
$arrayy[3]=21.31;
$arrayy[4]=48.62;
$arrayy[5]=21.31;
```

This function

```
function writeDouble($array){
        for($curr = 0; $curr<count($array)-1; $curr++){
            echo $array[$curr]." - ";
            echo $array[$curr+1]."<br>";
            $curr++;
    }
}
```

should write a couples (0-1 , 2-3 , 4-5) - an output like:

```
48.72 - 21.32
48.62 - 21.31
48.62 - 21.31
```

What am I doing wrong, why do I got an error?

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\lg\functions.php on line 466
```

Or could you define a better function to make couples? I can't think anymore... thanks

Comment: Yes. They are always even... hmm, ok. But why do I have this offset on my server?

Comment: Your code works fine according to this: http://codepad.org/cHdWSMMm.

Comment: What's the code on line 466 in your `functions.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're using `$array[$curr + 1]` but you're iterating from `0` to `$curr - 1`. You need an `isset` in case you have an odd number of values in your array.
2. You're incrementing 2 times (one time in your `for`, one time in the scope of your `for`).

Code solution:

```
$arrayy[0]=48.72;
$arrayy[1]=21.32;
$arrayy[2]=48.62;
$arrayy[3]=21.31;
$arrayy[4]=48.62;
$arrayy[5]=21.31;    

function writeDouble($array) {
        for ($curr = 0; $curr < (count($array) - 1); $curr += 2) {
            echo $array[$curr] . " - ";
            if (isset($array[$curr + 1])) {
              echo $array[$curr + 1];
            }
            echo "<br>";
    }
}

writeDouble($arrayy);
```

Output:

```
48.72 - 21.32
48.62 - 21.31
48.62 - 21.31
```

No more warning.

Comment: Ok, works.. as my example. Because warning was from different function :-) I'm kinda distracted today, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because in the last iteration in line `echo $array[$curr+1]."<br>";` you'll be looking for `$array[count($array)]` which is ofcource not defined!!

Comment: I subtracted "1" (-1) from size of cycle count($array) .

Comment: @user1666761 - But in the last iteration, $curr will be count($array)-1, which means $curr+1 will be one greater than count($array)-1

Comment: So, what do you suggest? After removing -1, error still stays.

Comment: iterating until count($array) -2

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are incrementing $curr two times:

```
for($curr = 0; $curr<count($array)-1; $curr++){
```

and

```
$curr++
```

This is the reason for going out of range in your loop

Comment: Because I need to do couples. So increment need to be by 2.

Comment: Oh I understand.  And thinking it better this is not the reason for an undefined index.  Make a var_dump($array) and check if the array is built as you state in your question.